# How to Create ISO / Installation Image from Our Own LFS(Linux From Scratch) Operating System in Qemu? I want to Make my Qemu.qcow2 image my Host OS

Tags: linux, rsync, lfs

I want to ask how to create an ISO, my OS is made with LFS 11.0 System V and I install it in Qemu. My Host OS is CAELinux.

The main concern is:

```
Is it possible to move the LFS OS installed in Qemu to replace my Host OS?
or should I just do LFS from zero toward my Host OS?
```

Here are my conditions:

- I do not use package manager
- PinguinEggs package can't be used to create ISO for my OS.
- I use Rsync to copy all files and symlinks from my LFS OS, but the problem is I do not know whether to delete all files in my CAELinux then Rsync all files from my LFS OS replacing the deleted CAELinux system files
- I have 2 SSD, one is for CAELinux, the other is still 95% free and already used to store the LFS OS I created through Rsync , do you think it is better to create dual boot? CAELinux + my LFS OS? Or just replace the CAELinux with my LFS OS?

Tell me if there is another better solution for this. I want to test my OS in the real hardware. The reason I want to create ISO is because I can install it in another PC/laptop.

Attached pictures:

1. The mounting Qcow' partition containing the main partition of my LFS OS (/usr /var /opt ..) The problem is there are more partitions from creating OS (nbd0p1 nbd0p2 nbd0p3 ..) How to create ISO or install this LFS OS to any hardware/laptop? Not just my current laptop because in the future hardware replacement / upgrading is inevitable.

[image: mountqcowinhost]

2. The mkisofs contain a lot of warnings: too many level of symbolic links (is it really going to work or should I just do LFS from zero toward my Host OS? )
   [image: mkisofs]
3. Using RSync works but I do not know how to proceed from this stage either to replace the host OS by my LFS OS or to create dual boot. [image: Partition in LFS OS]
   [image: The LFS OS in Qemu and the backup files in my Host OS]

Answer (score 0):

simply install the iso package

```
make rpm-pkg
make isoimage
```

and then download from other client PC.

Comment: I am not using Red Hat distribution

Answer (score 0):

Rizwan's answer might be your solution.

LFS could import RPM packages.

You might want to look at [this](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/introduction/beyond.html).